# Efficient way to store bigrams with count

Tags: hashmap, lisp, common-lisp

I have several text files and want to create bigrams with the count of the number of times these bigrams occur in my file. I was thinking I could store these in a hashmap with the bigrams as key, and count as value. However, I know that hashmaps use quite more memory than a list, and I was thinking I might be able to do the same thing with a list containing triples (w1, w2, count).

So, in code, I am doing this as of now:

```
(defparameter mymap (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(if (gethash "w1 w2" mymap) 
    (setf (gethash "w1 w2" mymap) (+ 1 (gethash "w1 w2" mymap))) 
    (setf (gethash "w1 w2" mymap) 1))
```

Comment: That's just `(incf (gethash "w1 w2" mymap 0))`.

Comment: "However, I know that hashmaps use quite more memory than a list," what's the basis for this claim?  A list will add a cons cell per entry, whereas a hash table might have a fixed size underlying array. Try both and profile before optimizing

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a small number of keys, a list is probably not what you want. A hashmap is probably a good choice. It may use a little more memory, but probably not enough that you need to worry about it, and you can tweak the `rehash-size` and `rehash-threshold` to control the memory/performance tradeoff for your particular application. (for example a small rehash-size and large rehash-threshold would use less memory, but take longer for lookups).

Another alternative is a binary search tree such as an AVL tree or Red-Black tree. These aren't included in the cl package, but there are several lisp libraries that provide implementations, including fset, lisp interface library, and cl-containers.